# Review Article on Black Holes

Tags: black-holes, resource-recommendations

I have interest in doing undergrad research involving black holes, and I'm looking for review articles about it, covering all the topic, from General Relativity to the astrophysics of black holes. I made a search in arXiv and other sites, but what I found was a compact review and an outdated one. If someone can tell me where do I find something better, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of references, check out Gallo and Marolf, ''Resource Letter BH-2: Black Holes''. For an excellent modern treatment of the subject, try *The Geometry of Black Holes* by Chrusciel (available online). Hope it helps. Oswaldo

Answer (score 3):

Instead of one single review article, I'd recommend that you go through a reading list of papers with great impact in the field. Emanuele Berti has put up an incredibly curated reading list for those wanting to dive into research in GR. Here is the link: [https://pages.jh.edu/~eberti2/posts/must-read-paper-list/](https://pages.jh.edu/%7Eeberti2/posts/must-read-paper-list/)