# Physics of black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, education

does anyone know good books and/or other sources of information regarding black hole mathematics/physics? Currently I'm reading the black hole wars by Leonard Susskind; it seems to be a collection of general explanations rather than a mathematical resource.

Comment: If you want a more detailed explanation that is given in popular science books like [The Black Hole War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole_War) you'll need to learn general relativity. Are you asking about introductory books on general relativity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488584/149907, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483400/149907, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/149907

Comment: There's Novikov's "Black Hole Physics", Eric Poisson's "A Relativist's Toolkit" and Shapiro's Black Holes, White Dwarfs and Neutron Stars. But these all assume you already know GR. So like what John Rennie said, if you want to study black holes do GR first. Try Schutz's "A First Course in General Relativity" or Hartle's "Gravity" or Hobson's "General Relativity".